# Multilingual translation for anonymous users

Tags: i18n-l10n, quiz

I have enabled i18n module in my site. But it didn't work properly for me.

I have created two quizzes in three languages with english language as a source language. I am using language dropdown block for switching to different languages.

The problem is that, the quizzes are translating to corresponding language well for administrator and authenticated users. But the quizzes are not properly translated for anonymous users. It remains in english only. 
   Same problem for basic page also.

I have checked permissions but I found there is no issue in permission. Please tell if anybody knows solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which module are you using for quizzes?  Also, are you using Varnish or any other type of caching?

Comment: @PatrickKenny I am using quiz module for creating quizzes. Yes. I am using memcache module.

Answer (score 3):

I found solution for my problem. The problem is in row weight of url present in detection and selection method in the path admin/config/regional/language/configure.

The row weight for url was -5 and row weight for default method was -6.
Then I changed row weight for url to -7. It works. Now the quizzes are translating properly for anonymous users also.